# Saving a Dynamically Created form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have created a sample form as

```
 Dim obj_CommonForm As New Form
 Dim btn_Create As New Button
 btn_Create.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(30, 200)
 btn_Create.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(60, 15)
 btn_Create.Text = "MyCommand"
 obj_CommonForm.Controls.Add(btn_Create)
 obj_CommonForm.Show()
```

Now I would like to save this form as .vb file and include it in my project.

Similar I have created in PHP where output html and saving as .php file is easy. This I have used as a initialize function as i start doing some project whose database has been created already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me... so I try to guess.

If you want to have a .vb file then you just have to take the .vb created by Visual Studio or by your application and include it in the project at compile time.

Instead if you are talking about a generic form created by your program and load it at runtime, you have to learn something about Serialization.

In latter case, I had your same problem some time ago and following article was a good starting point:

http://community.visual-basic.it/lucianob/archive/2007/10/14/20711.aspx

It is in Italian, but I think you can translate via some tool (except for code examples, obviously) :-)

Comment: I was thinking to create a .vb source file somewhere in my computer say c:\temp; This .vb source file should contain the code for a form that i create dynamically.

for example
a. I create a windows form application
b. In my application I create a hello world form
c. In hello world form, i create a button.
d. This button would create another test form (dynamically with some controls on it)
e. This test form need to be saved in some location as frmTest.vb file
f. I will include this .vb file in my another project as frmTest
g. I will add menu click event as frmTest.show() to show up this for

Comment: Then in my opinion it is much better to do what you need using Serialization